# Deploy azure keyvault with ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-keyvault, azure-cli, azureportal

When I create a keyvault with azure portal, before actual creating I have a link called "View Automation Template":
[image]

Where inside I can see a keyvault ARM template, but as I can see the azure cli command `az keyvault create ..` doesn't support options like `--template-file` or `--parameters`. How can I deploy the ARM template from the portal via azure CLI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CLI command you are looking for is [`az deployment group create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/deployment/group?view=azure-cli-latest#az-deployment-group-create) which makes use of an ARM template and parameters to deploy that template in a resource group.

You would use `az keyvault create` when you want to create a KeyVault resource by directly specifying its properties as command parameters instead of using an ARM template and parameters.

Answer (score 1):

> Where inside I can see a keyvault ARM template, but as I can see the azure cli command `az keyvault create ..` doesn't support options like `--template-file` or `--parameters`

Yes, You can deploy `ARM` template via azure CLI to create Azure Keyvault.

I have followed this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/keys/quick-create-template?tabs=CLI#review-the-template) to create `Azure Keyvault` with `ARM Template`.

**Azure CLI Command**

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup-Name" TemplateFile .\ARM.json
```

> Note: If you are running the command from the same directory, you can provide the template file as `.\<JSON File>`

**Output:**

[image]

If you want to use the `-TemplateParameterFile` option, you can create a parameter file separately in the same directory and use the command as shown below.

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup Name" TemplateFile .\ARM.json -TemplateParameterFile .\vault.parameters.json
```

Reference: [Create an Azure Key Vault using an ARM template](https://www.codeisahighway.com/create-an-azure-key-vault-using-an-arm-template-api-version-2015-06-01-and-azure-powershell-v1-0-4/)